# MS Edge is renaming downloads to "true.txt", "true.jpg", etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-edge

I have the following link:

```
<a download="true" href="/admin/employees/12/attachment">test.txt</a>
```

And in my controller for that route I have this:

```
def attachment
  response.headers['X-Download-Options'] = 'open'
  attachment = @employee.latest_attachment
  data = attachment.attachment_data.file_data
  send_data(data, disposition: 'attachment', filename: attachment.name, type: attachment.content_type)
end
```

Modern browsers all correctly download the file with the correct filename, but Edge changes the name to "true" + the correct extension.

How do I set the filename for Edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `download` tag on the link determines the filename for Edge, so instead of `true`, you should set it like:

```
<a download="my_filename" href="/admin/employees/12/attachment">my_filename.txt</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.